# Personalize password validation function used by accounts-ui

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

Meteor accounts uses the [following function](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled/login_buttons.js) to validate password format:

```
validatePassword = function (password) {
  if (password.length >= 6) {
    return true;
  } else {
    loginButtonsSession.errorMessage("Password must be at least 6 characters long");
    return false;
  }
};
```

Is it possible to overwrite this function? If so, how?

Comment: if you're looking to edit accounts-ui you will have to dig into the code to see if you can redefine it or you can create your own logic of account creation with http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser

Comment: I believe the question is relevant. There should be a recommended way as in the "Meteor way" (like there is a "Rails way") to solve this standard problem. This is not currently addressed in the Meteor docs.

Comment: You may also wish to refer to the Zen of Python 'There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

Comment: The original meteor accounts function is in this file: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled/login_buttons.js - for some reason the link was edited out by Stackoverflow editors...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser) Meteor does not send the password in clear through the wire. That's why you can't check the password on the server easily.

You could do one of the following though:

- **Create user via custom meteor method**

  You could build a custom login form which calls a Meteor.method which is defined on the server.
  In this meteor method call Account.createUser().

  example code (untested):

```js
Meteor.methods({
  createUser: function(email, password) {
    if (password.length < 5) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('password-too-short', 'Use longer password');
    }
    Accounts.createUser({email: email, password: password});
  }
});
```

```js
Meteor.call('createUser', email, password);
```

*Warning:* The password is sent in clear text to the server. Make sure to do have your DDP connection secured with SSL.

- **Check password on the client**

  Sure - you should never trust the client - but it's not very likely that a user modifies client side JavaScript code just to be able to set an easier password.

Comment: Thank you for answering and contributing to Stack Overflow, however please take a second look at the question, for it seems to be off-topic according to the [help/on-topic]. Answering off-topic question make it look like it's okay to ask such questions - it's not. Off-topic questions might get closed and then deleted, which would nullify your contribution!

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Though I think the question is relevant - but maybe with a different title like  "Server side password validation for Meteor accounts".

Comment: Well, it would require a different title, a different question, ... All in all it's not really salvageable.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the framework you are using. But ideally, you could use a regex and validate on both the front end and back end. For example:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.register.events({
    'submit form#password-form': function (e, template) {
      let pass = $(e.target).find('input[type="password"]');
      let passwordRegex = /\w{4,20}/gi   // this is just an example
      if (!passwordRegex.test(pass)) {
        // update dom as needed
      } else {
        Meteor.call('registerUser', $(e).serialize(), function (err, done) {
          if (!err) {
            // update for success
          } else {
            // update for failure
          }
        })
      }
    }
  });
} else {
  Meteor.methods({
    'registerUser': function (formObj) {
      check (formObj.password, String); // do all the checks first
      if (!/\w{4,20}/gi.test(formObj.password)) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(401, "Invalid password");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and contributing to Stack Overflow, however please take a second look at the question, for it seems to be off-topic according to the [help/on-topic]. Answering off-topic question make it look like it's okay to ask such questions - it's not. Off-topic questions might get closed and then deleted, which would nullify your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same problem this is my solution.

E.g. increase minimum password length from the default 6 to 8:

Add the following code in your client folder

```
 Accounts._loginButtons.validatePassword = function (password) {
  if (password.length >= 8) {
    return true;
  } else {
    Accounts._loginButtonsSession.errorMessage("Password must be at least 8 characters long");
    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you sure this actually works? All the calls to `validatePassword()` that I see in the meteor code don't have a `this` arg, so they would still execute the `validatePassword()` function that meteor defines.

Comment: I have confirmed that this does not work. See [this Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/5ksuXtKGjNmrs43j4/Personalize%20validatePassword).

Comment: @DeanBrettle - interesting -your Meteorpad uses accounts-ui-unstyled  - I am using ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 .

Comment: Your original question linked to `accounts-ui-unstyled` so I assumed you wanted to validate passwords while using that package. There are a variety of accounts UI packages that support custom validation but don't use `accounts-ui-unstyled`. In addition to `ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3`, another popular set of packages is the [`useraccounts`](http://useraccounts.meteor.com) suite.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, it isn't possible to override `validatePassword` directly, because it is private to the `accounts-ui-unstyled` package. However, it *is* possible (though not necessarily recommended) to override the client-side functions that pass the password to the server so that they will perform your custom validation first. Specifically you can do this:

```
//client only code

myValidatePassword = function (password) {
  if (password.length < 8) {
    throw new Meteor.Error("invalid-password", "Password must be at least 8 characters long");
  }
};

/* returns a function that will call beforeFunc(arguments) and 
   then call origFunc(arguments), using context for 'this' in 
   both cases. If beforeFunc throws an exception and the last 
   argument is a function, then that argument is assumed to be a
   callback function, and the callback function will be called 
   with the error.
   */
function addCallBefore(context, origFunc, beforeFunc) {
  return _.wrap(origFunc, function () {
    var args = _.rest(arguments);
    try {
      beforeFunc.apply(context, args);
    } catch (ex) {
      var callback = _.last(args);
      if (_.isFunction(callback)) {
        callback(ex);
        return;
      } else {
        throw ex;
      }
    }
    return origFunc.apply(context, args);
  });
}

Accounts.createUser = addCallBefore(Accounts, Accounts.createUser, function (options) {
    myValidatePassword(options.password);
});

Accounts.changePassword = addCallBefore(Accounts, Accounts.changePassword, function (oldPassword, newPassword) {
    myValidatePassword(newPassword);
});

Accounts.resetPassword = addCallBefore(Accounts, Accounts.resetPassword, function (token, newPassword) {
    myValidatePassword(newPassword);
});
```

[This meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/F27Tad6WWwy2wcG6t/Personalize%20validatePassword) demonstrates this.

Another option is to use the [`useraccounts`](http://useraccounts.meteor.com/) suite of packages instead of `accounts-ui`. The `useraccounts` suite provides [support for client-side validation](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#form-fields-configuration).